# Vim :fold of python code not different to C/C++ code

Tags: vim, python

When I enter the command `:fold` inside my python code in .py files, Vim inserts the `/*{{{*/` and `/*}}}*/` tags. They, of course, cannot be parsed by python interpreter.

When I'm in python I would like something like `#{{{`

Do you know how I could do that ? Of course, keeping the  `/*{{{*/` for my C/C++ files.

Comment: What is `commentstring` set to? For Python `:set commentstring=#%s` is reasonable, I guess.

Comment: how do I reset it for python only ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string used is determined by the variable `commentstring`. To set it to a different value you can use an autocommand:

```
augroup ft_python
  au!
  au FileType python setlocal commentstring=#%s
augroup END
```